# Error (no value) used as value en Golang

Tags: go

Tengo que realizar una función de ordenamiento de selección pasándole un vector y utilizando el máximo para ordenarlo, con las dos funciones auxiliares.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Swap(x *int, y *int) {
    aux := *x
    *x = *y
    *y = aux

}

func Maximo(vector []int) int {
    var pos int
    if len(vector) == 0 {
        return -1
    }

    maxValor := vector[0]

    for i := 0; i < len(vector); i++ {

        if vector[i] > maxValor {
            maxValor = vector[i]
            pos = i
        }
    }
    return pos
}

func Seleccion(vector []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(vector); i++ {
        mayor := len(vector) - i
        posMaximo := Maximo(vector)
        Swap(&vector[posMaximo], &vector[mayor-1])
        

    }

}

func main() {
    vector := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    Seleccion(vector)

}
```

Me da el siguiente error pero no lo entiendo:

> Swap(&vector[posMaximo], &vector[mayor - 1]) (no value) used as value.

¿Por qué me da ese error, y cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿Y el `return` de _Swap_?

Comment: Porque solo cambia la posición de los elementos, no devuelve ningún valor.

Comment: Justamente, si no devuelve ningún valor, ¿cómo entonces estás intentando que el valor de _res_ sea lo que retorna _Swap_?

Comment: Ahora, ¿cuál es el problema? Con la modificación que hiciste al código, ya no se muestra ningún mensaje de error. No olvides leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.